# Select all child entries and group by parent

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have the following data block -

```
+-----------+----------+
| parent_id | child_id |
+-----------+----------+
|         1 |       11 |
|         1 |       12 |
|         1 |       13 |
|         2 |       12 |
|         2 |       13 |
|         2 |       14 |
|         3 |       15 |
|         3 |       16 |
|         4 |       16 |
|         5 |       12 |
|         5 |       16 |
+-----------+----------+
```

I want to do a select statement where by I can find all child_id's that belong to parents and group the results, something like -

```
+-----------+----------+
| parent_id | child_id |
+-----------+----------+
|         1 | 12 & 13  |
|         2 |          |
+-----------+----------+ 
+-----------+----------+
| parent_id | child_id |
+-----------+----------+
|         1 |      12  |
|         2 |          |
|         5 |          |
+-----------+----------+
+-----------+----------+
| parent_id | child_id |
+-----------+----------+
|         3 |       16 |
|         4 |          |
|         5 |          |
+-----------+----------+
```

So parents **1** and **2** both have children **12** and **13**.
Parents **1,2 and 5** all have **12** as a child,
and **3,4 and 5** all have **16** as a child.

Comment: How are you choosing only those three sets?  There are lots of potential sets.

Comment: Not only those three sets @GordonLinoff, the sql would have to accommodate for all variations. I essentially need to determine which parents share the same children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table t1 WHERE t1.child_id = t.child_id AND t1.parent_id <> t.parent_id);
```

Comment: I have ran your sql and it does indeed bring back all records that I believe have one or more parents? However is it possible to group by parent_id?

Comment: @Ebikeneser. . . Yes you can include the `GROUP BY` clause with `OUTER Query` to shrink the overall data per `ParentId`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use cte get a result set which contains your expect  `parent_id` and `child_id` then use `FOR XML PATH` combine them with `&`.

finally use `row_number` window function create row number with `CASE WHEN` do condition aggregate function, let only first-row display `child_id`.

```
;with cte as (
    SELECT t1.*
    FROM T t1 
    where 
       EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM T tt WHERE t1.child_id = tt.child_id AND t1.parent_id <> tt.parent_id)
    AND 
       t1.parent_id in (1,2) --add you want to get parent_id id
), cte1 as (
     SELECT 
      distinct parent_id,
      STUFF((
         select  '&' + CAST(tt.child_id AS VARCHAR(MAX))  
         from cte tt 
         where t1.parent_id = tt.parent_id 
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)')
      ,1,1,'') AS child_id
     FROM cte t1
) 
SELECT parent_id,(case when rn = 1 then child_id else '' end) child_id
FROM (
   select *,row_number() over(order by parent_id) rn
   from cte1
) t1
```

[Sqlfiddle](https://rextester.com/TRU36876)

**Result**

```
parent_id   child_id
1           12&13
2
```

Comment: . . . Your demo nothing has to do with `C#`, then why you labeled a demo with name of `c# online`, Just a question ?